# Goblin XNA: Add color to only one GeometryNode

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, 3d-model

I have a GoblinXNA project with several imported (.fbx) models with materials.

When the user clicks on a node, I want to add a color mask to that node to indicate selection. I think I may need a BasicEffect or an Effect but I am not sure how to apply those to a single node.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(I am using XNA 4)